# Qt5 Deployed Application Not Showing GIF Image in QMovie

Tags: c++, qt, deployment, gif

I've been working on an application in Qt for a while now. I added an animated GIF image for a loading animations and it works perfectly deployed when running on my computer; However, on other computers, it's not showing up. I did a log check to make sure its finding the image and it is. I'm stuck right now and I'm not sure what to do now... I figured I need to include an extra dll or somethin like "zlib" but the one for GIF images but I don't know of one. Anybody think they know what can cause this?

I'm using: Qt 5.2.1, Windows 32-bit (VS 2010, OpenGL)

Example code:

```
QLabel *loadLabel = new QLabel();
QMovie *loadMovie = new QMovie(":/images/load_wheel.gif");
loadLabel->setMovie(loadMovie);
loadMovie->start();
```

Comment: Have you tried to check the imageformats plugins whether they are loaded properly?

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out about an hour of posting this.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was just missing the plugins folder required for it.